# Java Pattern Variable Scope

Tags: java, instanceof, java-17

I am going through Oracle's official [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) to understand **Pattern Variable scope** in Java 17. In the following example, the method `testScope1` works as explained in the docs, but the method `testScope2` gives a compilation error. I am not able to figure out why `void` return type of the method is causing the issue?

```
interface Vehicle{}
class Car implements Vehicle{}

class Pattern{
    public int testScope1(Vehicle v){
        if(!(v instanceof Car c)){
            return 1;
        }
        System.out.println(c.toString());  //WORKS FINE
        return 2; 
    }
    public void testScope2(Vehicle v){
        if(!(v instanceof Car c)){
                 
        }
        System.out.println(c.toString());  //COMPILE TIME ERROR: Cannot resolve symbol c
    }
}
```

Comment: "The scope of a pattern variable are the places where the program can reach only if the instanceof operator is true:"

Comment: Obviously the return type is not the cause -- it's the return statement.

Comment: I am also puzzled about this. Not having investigated, the given answers are all not very satisfactory for me. Regardless of the value at runtime, the scope of the variable is foggy for me. Since c gets introduced in the if expression, I'd expect it's scope to cover the expression and maybe the `then` and `else` code blocks, but nothing else. That way I am already surprised to read the first method is good. And yet I read "The scope of a pattern variable can extend beyond the statement that introduced it"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about what happens if `v` is **not** a `Car` instance:

- In `testScope1`, the `return 1;` statement causes the method to be exited. No subsequent statements of the method are exceuted. All is well.
- In `testScope2` there’s no `return`, so the control flow reaches `c.toString()`. But `v` isn’t a `Car`, so … what is `c`?! It can’t exist, because it would have to be of type `Car` but that’s a counterfactual. That’s why you’re getting the error “Cannot resolve symbol `c`”.

Answer (score 13):

Pattern variables (binding variables declared in patterns) use *flow-sensitive scoping*.  Unlike ordinary locals, which are in scope for in contiguous regions, pattern variables are in scope *where they would be definitely assigned by their declaring pattern*.

If you have an `if` statement:

```
if (x instanceof Foo(var v)) { 
    A;
}
else {
    B;
}
```

then `v` is in scope for `A`, but not for `B`, because we are not guaranteed that `v` would be definitely assigned a value in the cases where we reach `B`.  If we invert our test using the obvious refactoring:

```
if (!(x instanceof Foo(var v))) { 
    B;
}
else {
    A;
}
```

the same is true; `v` is in scope at `A` but not `B`.  The rules are exactly the same as the *definite assignment* rules for locals -- "is this value guaranteed to have been assigned a value if I reach this point."

Other conditional constructs, such as short-circuiting `&&` and `||`, also participate in this scoping.  For example, the following is valid:

```
if (x instanceof Foo(var v) && v != null) { 
    A;
}
```

but the following is not:

```
if (x instanceof Foo(var v) || v != null) { 
    A;
}
```

because in the latter, `v` is not guaranteed to have been assigned a value when we reach the `v != null` clause.

The rules even incorporate non-local control flow, such as exceptions.  For example, if we had:

```
if (!(x instanceof Foo(var v)) { 
    System.out.println("Not a Foo");
}
B(v);
```

this would be an error, since `v` is not guaranteed to have been assigned a value when we reach `B(v)`, but if the `if` block completes abruptly:

```
if (!(x instanceof Foo(var v)) { 
    throw new NotFooException();
}
B(v);
```

then `v` is in scope at `B(v)` because we are guaranteed that if we reach that point, `v` has been assigned a value.

This may look complicated, but it is actually quite simple: given what you know about the flow control of constructs like `if`, `throw`, etc, is a pattern variable guaranteed to have been assigned a value at a given point?  If so, it is in scope at that point.

Comment: You used a term `flow sensitive scoping`. Can you back this up by links, books or articles? I have heard it first time. And also articles linking it to `Pattern variable`. That would be helpful.
Because Practically it is no different `if-else` , `instanceof`, variable declaration`, `assignment` and plain old `variable scope` concept.

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq See, for example, JLS 6.3.1, "Scope for Pattern Variables in Expressions".  These rules may seem opaque at first, but they mirror the structure of Definite Assigment, which is a flow-based analysis.  There is a potentially more approachable explanation in https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/design-notes/patterns/pattern-match-semantics, under "Scoping of pattern variables".  (You seem to be working very hard to convince yourself that this is "the same as" something else you already understand, but the reality is more subtle.)

Comment: OP's question was about why he has to put a `return` or an `else` statement. In that context it is very helpful to know that this is what compiler is doing behind the scenes. If it were a debate on design patterns or language architecture or so, then most definitely you are correct, but have to look at it in OP's context  and thier confusion.

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq That's answered in the first sentence: pattern variables are in scope where they would be definitely assigned.  Because you can reach the use of `c` whether or not the pattern matches, there is no guarantee that `c` is definitely assigned when you reach the second `println` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Put an else statement. Pattern variable will be created only if `instanceof` operator yields `true`. Otherwise there is no variable in the scope, and hence the compiler error.

```
  public void testScope2(Vehicle v){
    if(!(v instanceof Car c)){

    } else {
      System.out.println(c.toString());
    }
  }
```

Edit:
`testScope1` method does not need `else` statement because the `return` statement is already there. `return` statement is ensuring that control never reaches `c.toString()` if `v` is not an instance of `Car`.

Pattern variable is just syntatic dark chocolate added in java 14. When bytecode is generated, it is no different from simple `instanceof` and `if-else` statements. Forexample, I compiled your `Pattern` class using java 17, and decompiled using java 8. Here is the decompiled version of `testScope1` method. Java 17 compiler has itself put an `else`:

```
public int testScope1(Vehicle var1) {
  if (var1 instanceof Car) {
    Car var2 = (Car)var1;
    System.out.println(var2.toString());
    return 2;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

So, you can see, the java compiler has modified your `if` statement, so that `Car` variable is created only if `v` is `instanceof` `Car`. Simple concepts `instanceof`, `TypeCasting`, `variable scopes`, and `if-else` have been used, which are there since long.

Comment: Why doesn't the `testScope1` method need else statement?

Comment: @Steve Because it doesn’t need it: the statement that is using `c` can never be reached if `v` isn’t a `Car` due to the `return`.

Comment: `testScope2` needs the `else` since there is NO  `return` inside the previous `if` block - `testScope1`  has a `return`, which basically works as an `else` for subsequent statements, so there is no need for an explicit `else`

Comment: @Steve (IMHO it is not the best practice to not have the `else` in `testScope1`. Also be aware that both methods, disregarding the different return declaration, are also logically different - in `testScope2` for example, the `println` after the `if` will always be executed)

Comment: When you say "there is no variable" you really mean "the variable is not in scope at this point."  Obviously there is a variable; its just that its scope does not include the entire program.

Comment: @BrianGoetz, yeah agreed. I just updated the line to `there is no variable in the scope`. Just one word added but sounds more complete.

Comment: Your claim of "just syntactic sugar" is inaccurate. Yes, pattern matching is lowered into `instanceof` and other JVM primitives, but to be "syntactic sugar" you would have to be able to express the lowered program in Java source, which often you cannot.  (Most developers have a pretty mushy and inaccurate notion of what "syntactic sugar" really means, so such misuses are common.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz Did you see my update? I literally expressed the lowered program in java source. Not me, java 8 decompiler did that.

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq Of course some programs using pattern matching can be expressed as lowered Java source -- but not all such programs can be.  Specifically, programs exist for which there is no way to express the exact scope of pattern variables through manual "desugaring", and you would have to artificially widen the scopes (and possibly rename some variables) to do so.  This is not mere "syntactic sugar."

Comment: @BrianGoetz I edited out the word syntatic sugar. But it sure is Syntatic Dark Chocolate. Isn't it? Since it is helping you reducing a few lines of code, making it simpler to express without adding anything new at bytecode(compiled code) level.

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq I think you're doing yourself a disservice by looking at it that way.  By this argument, everything in every programming language could be described as "syntactic fruitcake" for a Turing machine -- but that is negatively helpful in understanding how things work.  Pattern matching brings in a number of new concepts into the language, most of which are not syntactic in nature (e.g., new scoping rules, conditional vs unconditional patterns, pattern composition, etc.)  Trying to sweep this under the rug as "mere syntax" is anti-helpful.

Comment: OP's question was about why he has to put a return or an else statement. In that context it is very helpful to know that this is what compiler is doing behind the scenes. If it were a debate on design patterns or language architecture or so, then most definitely you are correct, but have to look at it in OP's context and thier confusion

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq if you want to focus on the OP’s problem instead of discussing language design aspects, then don’t bring in language design aspects like “syntactic sugar” or “syntactic dark chocolate”. Not even discussing bytecode is helpful. It’s enough to say that in this specific example, the source code is equivalent to what you’ve posted.

Comment: @Holger I want to focus on OP's question, the language concept, and also what goes behind the scenes in the compiler behind this concept. As a programmer, while learning new concepts, it is always helpful to know what goes behind the scenes behind any keyword or concept. Move on if you don't agree.

Answer (score 1):

Having spent more thoughts on this I have an explanation: The variable can only be accessed if the instanceof is clearly true for that piece of code.

In testScope1 you cannot access `c` within the if statement.
But since the code after the if statement only gets executed when the instanceof is true, `c` is accessible.

In testScope1 you cannot access `c` within the if statement.
But since the code after the if statement gets executed regardless of instanceof being true or false `c` is not accessible.
After all we might have the false situation and the compiler acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The "return" guarantees that the following code will not be reached. Therefore, it does not generate a compilation error.

```
public void testScope2(Vehicle v){
    if(!(v instanceof Car c)){
        System.out.println();
        return; //with this, works.  
    }
    System.out.println(c.toString());  //no more error
}
```