# What makes this variable accessible outside of block?

Tags: java

By mistake I learned that this code really works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = "Really?";
    if (!(o instanceof String s)) {
        System.out.println("darn!");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("This is happening? %s", s));
}
```

surprisingly compiles and produces:

```
This is happening? Really?
```

Meaning, variable `s` IS accessible outside of block it is declared in.

while replacing shown if statement with "equivalent" code:

```
if (o instanceof String s == false) {
```

leads to compilation error (as expected).

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744795/java-pattern-variable-scope) answer your question?

Comment: That looks very similar to the example in the docs titled "The scope of a pattern variable can extend beyond the statement that introduced it:" https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html#GUID-843060B5-240C-4F47-A7B0-95C42E5B08A7

Comment: If you change `if (!(o instanceof String s)) {` to `if (o instanceof String s) {`. it won't compile.

Comment: This is as specified in the relevant [JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) introducing these features. I highly recommend reading it. This is called _flow scoping_, and it behaves as if you've written `final String s; if (!(o instanceof String)) { return; } else { s = (String) o; }` Given `s` is definitely assigned after the `if`, you can use it.

Comment: @StephenC I understand that, what surprised me most is that replacement of `!` with `==false` won't compile and the flow scoping 'won't' work

Comment: Java Language Specification [6.3.1.5. Pattern Match Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1.5): "*It should be noted that there is no rule for introducing a pattern variable by `a instanceof p` when `false`.*" and there is no rule for `==`, but there is for `!` [6.3.1.3. Logical Complement Operator !](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1.3)

Comment: `== false` is bad style.  I'm not surprised that they don't have a rule for it.

Comment: @StephenC sure. But `==` can be applied to variable or function call. We can bypass this limitation via even worse style, but still, I'm surprised, that this is not supported, and on JDK level this shouldn't be based on bad-style argumentation. It's valid syntax and as such it should be supported if possible. And I'd like to know what stands in way of having uniform behavior of boolean expression evaluation.